# jQuery $(ui.draggable).remove() not working with IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I can get IE to remove objects as long as it is not the current draggable object.  This is working on Chrome and Firefox.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
    <li id="test-1" class="dropme">One</li>
    <li id="test-2" class="dropme">Two</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="bucket" style="border:1px solid black">
        <p>Drop items here and they should be removed.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#list").sortable({
        items: 'li'
    });   
    $('#bucket').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
        },
        accept: '.dropme'
    });   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does ui.draggable return exactly? In that selector does it not need to be a string of all draggable DOM elements? If it is then ignore this, I couldn't find it in the UI documentation. Also give the page a DOCTYPE as IE is probably in quirks mode and won't be working correctly.

Comment: `ui.draggable` is the currently dragged element in most jQuery UI drag events. In fact, it's already a jQuery object, there is no need to do `$(ui.draggable)`.

Comment: @Darth. Thanks, everyday's a schoolday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ui.draggable and drop function are a little quirky in IE. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
    <li id="test-1" class="dropme">One</li>
    <li id="test-2" class="dropme">Two</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="bucket" style="border:1px solid black">
        <p>Drop items here and they should be removed.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#list").sortable({
        items: 'li',
        stop: function(event, ui) { 
            if (deleteMe) {
                        ui.item.remove();
                        deleteMe = false;
                    }
        }
    });   
    $('#bucket').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            deleteMe = true; 
        },
        accept: '.dropme'
    });   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked!  Much appreciated.  I hate special coding for IE!  errr!