# jQuery .remove() returns error in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have Firebug Lite running in IE9 testing my website and for some reason when I try to run a simple command to remove a div it returns the error "TypeError: Object expected". Here is what I am running:

```
$("#drag-hoverbox_you").remove();
```

This works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. A div with the id "drag-hoverbox_you" definitely exists...

Comment: Post your code, because it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/fqYPs/ (IE 9)

Comment: *"A div with the id "drag-hoverbox_you" definitely exists..."* Even if it didn't, jQuery would return a valid object wrapping an empty set. You're *sure* you're using jQuery? Not some other library that also uses `$`? (Don't laugh, that was actually the answer to a question last week.)

Comment: sidenote: why use firebug lite. IE9 has a decent console...

Comment: From what i can see this is a draggable + remove issue in IE. Please check the following stackoverflow issue that duplicates your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994990/jquery-ui-draggable-remove-not-working-with-ie

Comment: @Christoph. Has a console sounds better...

Comment: @gdoron compared to earlier IE (absent) consoles it is definitely decent;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an older version of jQuery-UI to make my windows draggable. The error was being returned because there was a flash object inside of the draggable DIV that I was trying to remove. The newer version of jQuery-UI won't even allow you to make DIVs that contain flash objects draggable. So I can now delete div containers, but I'm unable to make them draggable. Thanks for everyones' help!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid another downvote bombardment, I've tested this with IE9 first.

Add this to CSS

```
.iefix {
display:none;
}
```

and make your drop function remove in this manner

```
$("#drag-hoverbox_you").addClass("iefix").remove();
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Certainly not just in the normal case, can you expand on the reasons for this?

Comment: `To avoid another downvote bombardment, I've tested this with IE9 first.`...I would hope that people in general test an answer before posting it to ensure the information is correct rather than due to the fear of downvotes.

Comment: OP's question is about the .remove() method in JQuery, in my previous answer I provided a working code in IE9. For some reason, the OP neglected to mention he's using draggable so this time I tested it specifically with draggable. Because apparently, if you use the OP's low quality input to provide a correct answer.. you'll still be downvoted.